# Array of pointers confusion with skip list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, skip-lists

I think I have a basic understanding of how skip lists work, but being new to them in addition to being a C-beginner has me confused on a few points, especially the initialization of the list. Here's the code I'm trying to follow:

```
#define MAXSKIPLEVEL 5

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next[1]; 
} Node;

typedef struct SkipList {
    Node *header;
    int level;
} SkipList;


// Initialize skip list
SkipList* initList() {

    SkipList *list = calloc(1, sizeof(SkipList));

    if ((list->header = calloc(1, sizeof(Node) + MAXSKIPLEVEL*sizeof(Node*))) == 0) {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSKIPLEVEL; i++)
        list->header->next[i] = list->header;

    return list;
}
```

I haven't done anything with arrays of pointers yet in C, so I think I'm getting a bit caught up with how they work. I have a few questions if someone would be kind enough to help me out.

First, I did `sizeof(int)` and got 4, `sizeof(Node*)` and got 8, so I expected `sizeof(Node)` to equal 12, but it ended up being 16, why is this? Same confusion with the size of `SkipList` compared to the sizes of its contents. I took the `typedef` and `[1]` out to see if either of them was the cause, but the size was still 16.

Second, why is the [1] in `struct Node *next[1]`? Is it needed for the `list->header->next[i]` later on? Is it okay that `next[i]` will go higher than 1? Is it just because the number of pointers for each node is variable, so you make it an array then increase it individually later on?

Third, why does `list->header->next[i] = list->header` initially instead of `NULL`?

Any advice/comments are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `SkipList *list = calloc(1, sizeof(SkipList));` - you forgot to check this for failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question - why isn't the size of the `struct` the size of its members? - this is due to *struct padding*, where the compiler, usually for alignment reasons, may add in extra blank space between or after members of a `struct` in order to get the size up to a nice multiple of some fundamental size (often 8 or 16). There's no portable way to force the size of the struct to be exactly the size of its members, though most compilers have some custom switches you can flip to do this.

For your second question - why the `[1]`? - the idea here is that when you actually allocate one of the node `struct`s, you'll overallocate the space so that the memory at the end of the `struct` can be used for the pointers. By creating an array of length one and then overallocating the space, you make it syntactically convenient to access this overallocated space as though it were a part of the `struct` all along. Newer versions of C have a concept called *flexible array members* that have supplanted this technique; I'd recommend Googling it and seeing if that helps out.

For your final question - why does `list->header->next[i]` initially point to `list->header` rather than `NULL`? - without seeing more of the code it's hard to say. Many implementations of linked list structures use some sort of trick like this to avoid having to special-case on `NULL` in the implementation, and it's entirely possible that this sort of trick is getting used here as well.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. I changed `malloc`s to `calloc` in my code so I could take out some 0 and NULL initialization lines, is this bad practice for any reason or was it fine to do?

Comment: That's fine - it's one of the main reasons why people use `calloc`. It doesn't hurt to document it with a comment so that whoever reads the code has an easier time maintaining it.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` number is 16 because of *structure padding*.

Many architectures either **require** or **strongly prefer** their pointers to be aligned on a certain boundary (e.g., 4-byte boundary, 8-byte boundary, etc.) They will either fail, or they will perform slowly, if pointers are "misaligned". Your C compiler is probably inserting 4 unused bytes in the middle of your structure so that your 8-byte pointer is aligned on an 8-byte boundary, which causes the structure size to increase by 4 bytes.

There is more explanation available from the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html).